# How do i change the video lightbox size using the css

Tags: css

I am using the videobox code to display the video in the light box.
This code uses the `rel` attribute of link.
Now I need to change the video display size through CSS, because my template is responsive and I need to change the video size according to device resolutions.

for example

```
<a id="videobox-link" href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gZzZ14QJIWM" title="The process
```

is simple and everyone wins!" rel="vidbox 560 315">

I need to change the `rel="vidbox 560 315"` parameter 560 and 315 through CSS.
How can I do that.

Can you please guide me on this

Comment: Please show us some code.

Comment: _the videobox code_. What is that? Also, you can't change the `rel` attribute trough CSS (I think)

Answer (score 0):

info from website [videobox](http://videobox-lb.sourceforge.net/):
**You can also start your videos with javascript.**

```
Videobox.open("your video page url","your caption","vidbox widht height");
```

use java script for detect windows width and add width, height attributes